# Deploying node_modules with Nextjs on an IIS application

Tags: iis, next.js, azure-devops, deployment, node-modules

I've succesfully deployed my Nextjs application on an IIS application (so root/subapplication). I do have some issues however. The way I currently deploy the application is by running `next build` and copying the build output (the `.next` folder) to the build folder that the IIS application looks at. Currently I also copy the node_modules and a custom web.config and server.js to the build folder. An `iisnode` folder is then later added by IISNode. So the folder looks like this:
`|next-build`
`|_ .next`
`|_ node_modules`
`|_ web.config`
`|_ server.js`
`|_ iisnode`

**The problem:**

When I add CI/CD into the mix, running a pipeline on our Azure Devops server, building an artifact and placing the artifact in build folder, the node_modules don't get updated. I know that `Nextjs` has a `standalone` output that includes the `node_modules` in the build but that version doesn't work as it can't find the node_module (issue has been addressed on the Vercel forums).

Surely there must be another way to add the node_modules automatically. I've been thinking about adding the possibility of adding a script to the staging area that run a yarn install when done. I don't know if this is possible as I've very little experience with Azure Devops. This would then require me to add the `package.json` instead.

Does anyone have any experience with this? I'd love to hear some ideas or suggestions.

**Server.js**

```
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
    createServer((req, res) => {
        const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
        const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;
        console.log(parsedUrl);
        console.log(req.headers);
        if (pathname.startsWith('/next-build')) {
            const page = pathname === '/next-build' ? '/' : pathname.substring('/next-build/'.length);
            return app.render(req, res, page, query);
        } else {
            return app.render(req, res, '/next-build', query);
        }
    }).listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
});
```

**Update: Added YAML**

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  name: BuildServer

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g yarn
  displayName: 'npm install yarn'

- script: |
    yarn install
  displayName: 'yarn install'

- script: |
    npm run build
  displayName: "run build"

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: $(build.SourcesDirectory)/.next
    ArtifactName: deploy
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Error: [image: Error message]

Step to reproduce:

- create a Next.js application by running `npx create-next-app@latest` (use pages, not app router)
- Add a a basepath in your next.config.js with the name of your application in IIS, so in my case: basePath: "/next-build"
- Push your code to Azure DevOps
- Add a new pipeline, point to where you have the code
- Add the yaml file attached
- Run the pipeline and copy download the artifact
- Unzip the artifact and place it in a buildfolder
- Open IIS
- Create an application pool, give it the correct rights
- Use Default Web Site, underneath Sites and create an application
- Give the application a name (e.g. next-build) and select the application pool you made earlier.
- Set the physical path to buildfolder you made earlier.
- Make sure the user that approaches the site and application also has the correct rights
- Install the modules iisnode and url rewrite
- Add the following web.config from this article to your build folder: https://medium.com/@dipneupane/deploying-nextjs-application-on-windows-iis-server-cabdc22bccf8
- Add the Server.js posted earlier to build folder as well.
- Browse the application

Comment: 1. Please try to run `yarn install` or `npm install` to install all dependencies before the build. For example, `- script: yarn install`. 2. According to your description, it seems that you published the node_modules into the artifact. If so, please go to your build summary page and check whether node_modules was updated in the pipeline artifact from the UI. 3. To learn more info about your pipeline, it's suggested that you could share the yaml file of your pipeline. Don't forget to remove your personal info.

Comment: I added the yaml from the pipeline.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT I also added the error I get when I deploy it like this. Adding node_modules manually fixes it but it's not the wanted result.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT I can already see the Artifact after running the pipeline, what does changing the location to Azure Pipelines do specifically?

Comment: sorry, I didn't see your yaml when I added the previous comment. To avoid misunderstanding, I have deleted it.  1. Regarding "the node_modules don't get updated", would you please let me know if there is no `node_modules` in the artifact, or if there is `node_modules` but it is not the latest version? 2. Please check **Enable system diagnostics** option when you trigger the pipeline.  Then check in the debug log, what is the path to the `.next` folder? 3. If it's convenient, would you please share a sample project so that I can test from my side.

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT Thank you for your insightful replies. I'll update my answer with steps to reproduce it. 1) I can't see any `node_modules` in the artifact, however I do see a webpack folder with a client-production and server-production file that contain node_module-like lines. Nothing called node_modules though. 2) I enabled system diagnostics and this the last line the `PublishBuildArtifact` task gave me: `Upload 'C:\Agents\TFSBUILD2\_work\19\s\.next' to file container: '#/60864/deploy'`
3) I'll provide the steps in my original post.

Comment: Tested in my pipeline, I can't see `node_modules` in `.next` folder. Please try to change 'PathtoPublish' to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` and check what's the result.

Comment: This worked, as in it includes the node_modules, but the artifact is now massive (781 MB) and it doesn't look like the .next build folder and took 32 minutes to process. It actually looks like my regular nextjs project.